# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - pygsp modules not callable

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to implement graph signal processing in pygsp by follwoing the documentation. PyGSP version I am using in 0.5.1 and is imported successfully but am not able to use any of its modules.

```
import pygsp

G = pygsp.graphs.logo()
f = pygsp.filters.Heat(G)
Sl = f.analysis(G.L.todense(), method='cheby')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "C:/Users/SAI_SHREYASHI_PENUGO/Documents/.../gsp_trial1.py", line 3,  
   in <module>
    G = pygsp.graphs.logo()
   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Expected for it to compile without errors considering I have pygsp installed in the list of site-packages where all other packages are stored(which are being accessed without any error).

Comment: Where did you see this in documentation? *[`pygsp.graphs.logo`](https://github.com/epfl-lts2/pygsp/blob/master/pygsp/graphs/logo.py)* is a module, not a function, class or other callable. Probably, you need [`pygsp.graphs.Logo`](https://pygsp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/graphs.html#pygsp.graphs.Logo) instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you that solved it. My terminology was wrong, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly pointed out in comments, `pygsp.graphs.logo` is a [pygsp module](https://pygsp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pygsp/graphs/logo.html?highlight=Logo).
There are a couple of errors too.

The correct way to use the module is as follows.

```
import pygsp

G = pygsp.graphs.Logo()
f = pygsp.filters.Heat(G)
Sl = f.analyze(G.L.todense(), method='chebyshev')
```

You can now view one of the filtered signal on the graph by

```
pygsp.plotting.plot_signal(G, Sl[0])
pygsp.plotting.show()
```

[image: Output Image]